# JDeveloper mark occurrences automatically

Tags: ide, jdeveloper

I know that Oracle JDeveloper has "mark occurences" function. It's possible to highlight desired variables/methods in 2 ways:

1. Ctrl + Alt + H
2. From the menu Search -> Code Highlight

I would like to make "highlighting occurrences" work automatically, as in the Eclipse, is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From "Search" menu -> "Auto Code Highlight"

Answer (score 0):

from tools > preferences > Code Editor > Find Options > then tick "Highlight All Occurrences"